# Background image gets cut off, even though form and image size match

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to create a Ludo game using Windows Forms.
I have set the background to be the image of a ludo board, where both the image and the window have the same size (960x960). I cannot use the image stretch feature, as it will mess with the button positions on my Form.

The Form has the bottom and the right side of the background image trimmed off, even though the Form matches the size of the background image.

[image: ludo game]

Comment: When you set the Size property of a Form in the PropertyGrid, the generated code in the `.Designer.cs` actually sets - as the answer suggests - the `ClientSize` property, recalculated based on the current non-client area of a Form -- You'll have to consider how the image is rendered in Screens with a different DPI resolution in any case

Answer (score 1):

The `Size` of the form is the outer dimensions. You should set the `ClientSize` of your form to the `Size` of the `Image`, which you can do in code. That way, the image and form will look correct no matter what window chrome is or isn't present.

Comment: The answer above is the way to go, however you could also just account for the window chrome by making the form bigger than the image. As the image dimensions need to be the size of the content and not the window, ex. `Content = 960x960` and `Window = 980x1024`.

Comment: @SimpleCoder, your terminology seems to suggest that you're talking about WPF rather than WinForms.

Comment: It doesn't really matter it's the same problem, he doesn't account for the titlebar and therefore his board is smaller. Although the terminology is more WPF than WinForms it is basically the same concept.

Comment: Hi! I am so sorry for not replying, I need to find a way to get notifications but besides the point. 

@user18387401 unfortunately this won't work because I am using framework 6.0. Now I am also having a problem with even displaying the image?! It might be because I have changed displays from 1080 to 1440 but the  images are loading terribly, not even anywhere near resolution.

Comment: @SimpleCoder thanks for the try but this is really not working properly,  my form is beginning to look stretched even with no "stretch" option being enabled. Everything is much wider than it should be.